# Translate CSS transition-timing-function to swiping

Tags: css, animation, math, transition, timing

I am fading in a div (using CSS transitions) with a custom timing function (http://cubic-bezier.com/#1,0,1,1). The timing function is basically a more extreme version of 'ease-in'.

```
div {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

.in {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

In addition to that, I want to be able to fade in the div by swiping across the screen. I am using the following Jquery to set the opacity according to how far the user has swiped:

```
documentWidth = $(document).width();

$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {

    // How much of the animation is completed (in %)
    completion = e.changedTouches[0].pageX / documentWidth;

    $('div').css('opacity', completion);
})
```

Nooooow, this is linear! Is there a clever Math-person out there who can figure out how to re-state that last line to represent my timing function?

So, for example, if `completion` is at 25%, the opacity should be around 2%. At 50%, it should be around 11% and at 75% it should be around 31%.

Comment: Why don't you work with `animation` instead of `transition` and then define your parameters accordingly in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by finding a curve that approximates your `cubic-bezier` curve. With the given points and some [online tools](https://mycurvefit.com/) it's possible to draw a curve with this equation:

```
y = 464085.7 + (0.0174619 - 464085.7)/(1 + (x/22.88957)^4.174069)
```

in your case the `x` represents your `completion` variable and `y` the resulting opacity.

Then your code becomes

```
let completion = e.changedTouches[0].pageX / documentWidth;
let exponential = Math.pow((completion / 22.88957), 4.174069);
let opacity = 464085.7 + (0.0174619 - 464085.7)/(1 + exponential);

$('div').css('opacity', opacity);
```

(of course you may find a better equation that best fits your needs)

Comment: That's an awesome tool. Thanks!